# Need to put date within quotes

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a date to a function that calculates the age of a person. However, the date is in Y-m-d format in the database, and I need to pass it in "Y-m-d" format. I have tried string concatenation, but that failed, maybe because it just operated the numbers using minus(-) operator. Kindly let me know how to do the same.

I am fetching the DOB in $dob variable, and passing it to CalculateAge($dateofbirth) function

Here is the code:

```
function CalculateAge($BirthDate)
{
        // Put the year, month and day in separate variables
        list($Year, $Month, $Day) = explode("-", $BirthDate);

    //echo $Year;       

        $YearDiff = date("Y") - $Year;
        // If the birthday hasn't arrived yet this year, the person is one year younger
        if(date("m") < $Month || (date("m") == $Month && date("d") < $Day))
        {
                $YearDiff--;
        }
    if(date("m") > $Month || date("m") == $Month)
        $MonthDiff = date("m") - $Month;
    else
        $MonthDiff = 12 - $Month + date("m");

    $age = $YearDiff + $MonthDiff/12;
        return $age;
}
$dob = mysql_query("SELECT date_of_birth FROM kids_informations WHERE user_id = '$usid'");  
$rs = CalculateAge($dob);
```

Comment: Lets see what you tried.

Comment: If `$dateofbirth` is a string, no need to quote it.

Comment: We need more details, currently what you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Any example code?
Sound to me like this would be more easy to do in an SQL query, but without knowing what you're trying to do it's impossible to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably work -

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date_of_birth FROM kids_informations WHERE user_id = '$usid'");  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $dob = $row['date_of_birth'];
}

$dob = "\"".$dob."\"";

$rs = CalculateAge($dob);
```

Comment: On echoing $dob, I get this: Resource id #32

Comment: See the edit. I am not sure though, you could find an easier way to get date_of_birth ...

Comment: Got it finally! Your solution partially worked, as I had to remove the " from the start of the year string! Thanks for your effort!
Kindly add this line to the function CalculateAge(dob) after the list statement, so that I may mark your answer as the correct one: $year = substr($Year, 1);. Had to replace the variable $Year with $year in the next line!

Answer (score 0):

use this: `echo date("\"Y-m-d\"");`